# Magento 2: phone number validation (only accepts numbers)

Tags: magento2, checkout, validation, form-validation

In Magento 2, I want to make phone fields number validation, (eg in the checkout page) only accepts numbers (and not characters)?

Answer (score 10):

To validate number you can use `validate-number` in your module `checkout_index_index.xml` file.

Like ::

```
<item name="telephone" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="tooltip" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="description" xsi:type="string" translate="true">For delivery questions</item>
    </item>
    </item>
    <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="min_text_length" xsi:type="number">10</item>
        <item name="max_text_length" xsi:type="number">10</item>
        <item name="validate-number" xsi:type="number">0</item>
    </item>
</item>
```

Comment: Thanks this is working only for billing address can you suggest what i can do for shipping address

Comment: Also, validate-number allows hyphen (-) in the beginning

Comment: yes right, with billing address its working fine but with shipping address its not working. any suggestion?

Answer (score 9):

form should be like

```
<form class="form contact"
  action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getFormAction(); ?>"
  id="contact-form"
  method="post"
  data-hasrequired="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('* Required Fields') ?>"
  data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
```

now in input field use **data-validate="{'validate-number':true}"**

Your input would look like

```
<input type="text" data-validate="{'validate-number':true}">
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

You have  to do add `data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'` inside form declaration as following:

```
<form class="form contact"
      action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getFormAction(); ?>"
      id="contact-form"
      method="post"
      data-hasrequired="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('* Required Fields') ?>"
      data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
```

Use class validate-number

I hope it will help you.