# Magento 2 checkout postcode validation only numbers

Tags: magento2, onepage-checkout, validation

Magento 2 in checkout page postcode, I want to restrict alphabets allowed only numbers, how can I set by using a validation XML file?

I tried below link for postcode [validation number](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/113963/magento-2-phone-number-validation-only-accepts-numbers)

```
<item name="postcode" xsi:type="array">
     <!-- post-code field has custom UI component -->
     <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/post-code</item>
     <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="string">true</item>
      <item name="validate-number" xsi:type="number">0</item>
    </item>
    </item>
```

Please help me

Comment: @PrathapGunasekaran I have update my question  have placed Already but not worked

Comment: es onepage checkout i have place one page checkout file only